# Colon instead of ", p. X" for direct quotes biblatex-ieee

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style, quotation

I'm new here and ask you to help me with my issue. I hope that I can provide all necessary information for that.

According to [this guide](http://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/ieeereferencing/gettingstarted) it IEEE referencing requires to style direct quotes in another way than a paraphrase.
Direct quotes should look like this [1: 100] and paraphrases like that [1, p. 120].

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee,bibencoding=UTF8]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Issue}
\begin{quote}
    A long direct quote. \cite[42]{man20}
\end{quote}
Some content \cite[1337]{she20}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is the content of the bib-file:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@Book{man20,
  author    = {Man, A},
  title     = {Men},
  publisher = {The MEN},
  year      = {2020},
}
@Book{she20,
  author    = {She, The},
  title     = {Women},
  publisher = {The WOMEN},
  year      = {2020},
}
```

Are you able to give me a solution for this? My Google searches didn't lead to anything.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/IEEE-Reference-Guide.pdf doesn't seem to suggest there is a difference between direct and indirect citations. In fact I could not find the [1: 100] form there at all. Are you sure the information you have found is reliable? (The question is interesting nevertheless, but I'm afraid it is too later where I am to look into this, but I will have a look tomorrow if no one else has tackled the question until then.)

Comment: I found this method in another source, too. It could be that this way of citation is deprecated. The newest IEEE styleguide gives no information on a difference between paraphrasing and direct quotes at all.

Probably it's the best to ask my professor how he wants it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is just to make a new `\directcite` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@Book{man20,
  author    = {Man, A},
  title     = {Men},
  publisher = {The MEN},
  year      = {2020},
}
@Book{she20,
  author    = {She, The},
  title     = {Women},
  publisher = {The WOMEN},
  year      = {2020},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\directcite}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \bibopenbracket
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{##1}}%
   \DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \bibclosebracket
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
    A long direct quote. \directcite[42]{man20}
\end{quote}
Some content \cite[1337]{she20}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly :)